# mpeg_decode_postinit() failure

Tags: linux, centos, ffmpeg, capture

I'm trying to take some thumbnails via ffmpeg command. My file name is "aaa.ts" and I want to take some thumbnails every second.

Frankly, it works, but I have 4 red lines in terminal. So can you tell me what kinds of problem I have and give me some solutions?

My command was:
`ffmpeg -i aaa.ts -r 1 screenshot%03d.png`

It makes some pngs in the directory, but the very first two or three are completely grey and the output from the command have these four errors.

1. [mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]mpeg_decode_postinit() failure
2. [mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]warning: first frame is no keyframe
3. [mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]ac-tex damaged at 31 60
4. [mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]Warning MVs not available

**Complete log**

```
[juneyoungoh@localhost Videos]$ ffmpeg -i aaa.ts -r 1  screenshot%03d.pngFFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mpeg2video @ 0x2609d10]mpeg_decode_postinit() failure
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'aaa.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.62, start: 16912.065044, bitrate: 18146 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x11]: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19190 kb/s, 34.70 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x14](): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to 'screenshot%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg2video @ 0x2609d10]warning: first frame is no keyframe
frame=    3 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=3.00 bitrate=  -0.1kbits/s dup=0 frame=    4 fps=  3 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=4.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 frame=    5 fps=  3 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=5.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 frame=    6 fps=  2 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=6.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 [mpeg2video @ 0x2609d10]ac-tex damaged at 31 60
[mpeg2video @ 0x2609d10]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x2609d10]concealing 960 DC, 960 AC, 960 MV errors
frame=    6 fps=  2 q=0.0 Lsize=      -0kB time=6.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=122    
video:12381kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000174%
[juneyoungoh@localhost Videos]$ ffmpeg -r 1  -i aaa.ts screenshot%03d.pngFFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mpeg2video @ 0x20c3d10]mpeg_decode_postinit() failure
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'aaa.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.62, start: 16912.065044, bitrate: 18146 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x11]: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19190 kb/s, 34.70 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x14](): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to 'screenshot%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg2video @ 0x20c3d10]warning: first frame is no keyframe
frame=   10 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.33 bitrate=  -0.5kbits/s dup=9 frame=   12 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.40 bitrate=  -0.4kbits/s dup=9 frame=   14 fps=  8 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.47 bitrate=  -0.4kbits/s dup=9 frame=   16 fps=  6 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.53 bitrate=  -0.3kbits/s dup=9 frame=   18 fps=  5 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.60 bitrate=  -0.3kbits/s dup=9 frame=   19 fps=  5 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.63 bitrate=  -0.3kbits/s dup=9 frame=   21 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.70 bitrate=  -0.3kbits/s dup=9 frame=   23 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.77 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   24 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.80 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   26 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.87 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   28 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=0.93 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   30 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=1.00 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   31 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=1.03 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   33 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=1.10 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   35 fps=  4 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=1.17 bitrate=  -0.2kbits/s dup=9 frame=   36 fps=  3 q=0.0 Lsize=      -0kB time=1.20 bitrate=  -0.1kbits/s dup=9 drop=0    
video:60368kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000036%
[juneyoungoh@localhost Videos]$ ffmpeg -i aaa.ts -r 1  screenshot%03d.png
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 23:55:02 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]mpeg_decode_postinit() failure
    Last message repeated 10 times
Input #0, mpegts, from 'aaa.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:04.62, start: 16912.065044, bitrate: 18146 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0.0[0x11]: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19190 kb/s, 34.70 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x14](): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to 'screenshot%03d.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]warning: first frame is no keyframe
frame=    3 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=3.00 bitrate=  -0.1kbits/s dup=0 frame=    4 fps=  3 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=4.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 frame=    5 fps=  3 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=5.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 frame=    6 fps=  2 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=6.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 [mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]ac-tex damaged at 31 60
[mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x24bed10]concealing 960 DC, 960 AC, 960 MV errors
frame=    6 fps=  2 q=0.0 Lsize=      -0kB time=6.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=122    
video:12381kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000174%
```

thanks very much. this problem has solved. it was version problem just like what Nick said. Thanks again:D

Comment: You are using an old FFmpeg version (version 0.6.x is from 2010), try to update to a recent version first. This probably solves your problem.

Comment: @NickvanTilborg I know it's idiot question, but which is the most new version of ffmpeg? and how can I update in terminal. Franky, I'm so new in linux system, I can not find where it is;; give me some hint :D

Comment: The best way, in my opinion, is downloading the latest sourcefiles from [FFmpeg Downloads](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Then run the `configure` and `make` commands to compile the program. [Compiling FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) can help you out. Also a simple google throws thousands of hits on installing FFmpeg on a server.

Comment: If you don't want to build anything, you can also run a static build from the download page (http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) if your kernel isn't too old.

Comment: I have the same error message with avconv command built on Mar 16 2015 13:26:50 with gcc 4.6.3. This question is not localized at all not in geographic area nor in time, please reopen